# Hall $\pi$-subgroups of normal subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $A$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ such that $H\in$ Hall$_\pi$($A$) and $G/A$ is a $\pi$-group.

Suppose that $H = H_1 \cap A$ where $H_1 \in$ Hall$_\pi$($G$). Show that $H^A = H^G$ where $H^G = \{gHg^{-1} \;|\; g\in G\}$

Clearly we have that $G = AH_1$ and $H^A \subseteq H^G$

Let $x\in H^G$ then $x = gHg^{-1}$ for some $g \in G$. Also $g = ah_1$ where $a\in A$ and $h_1 \in H_1$

I'm not sure how to proceed

Comment: $h_1 \in H$, so $ah_1H{h_1}^{-1}a^{-1}=aHa^{-1}$.

Comment: @NickyHekster I don't see why $h_1 \in H$, but $H \unlhd H_1$ so $h_1Hh_1^{-1}=H$.

Comment: Derek yes I interchanged $H$ and $H_{1}$, you are right of course.